# Highscore saving Issue

Tags: javascript, cordova

Hello I have this game in javascript. The issue with it is that, every time when I close the game and restart, the highscore gets set back to 0. If anyone can help me on here. I can send my code to him. It in phonegap (Cordova).

Comment: did you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please explain what your problem is in more detail, and include relevant parts of the code. Also, Java is not the same as JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use cookies to store the highscores of the player. [Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

However, using cookies will only store data locally on that computer and can be easily removed by the user. So, instead of using javascript, you could also use [PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp) and [MYSQL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp) to store the data in the server.